# Can't update iPad 3 to iOS 9.3.5

Tags: ios, ipad

I have an iPad 3, running iOS 8.3. I am unable to update it to iOS 9.3.

When checking for Software Update in Settings app, it says that I have the latest version installed.

How do I update it to iOS 9.3.5?

Comment: Can you check if you have an active Internet connection.

Comment: Internet connection active, In iTunes the same

Comment: You can take a backup in iTunes, restore the iPad with iOS 9.3.5 image (download the image from https://ipsw.me/#!/platform) using iTunes and restore from backup.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Your comment doesn't really clarify the question and would be better as an answer. For about 1/3 of the questions here - people don't know how to triage or troubleshoot something so rather than answering in the comments - embracing that the question is a plea for options or guidance - go ahead and stake out a positive answer. You can even say "Based on the details - this needs some triage - here's the triage by Apple article (or other link) - here's what I'd try first - and here's what we don't know so maybe a follow up question is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked in Settings>General>About to verify your current OS version?

Sometimes if you check and then restart the device and then check again, that clears things.

Answer (score 2):

Start by checking the version of iOS currently installed on your iPad by going to Settings app → General → About reading the value for **Version**.

If the reported version is still iOS 8.3, you can restore your iPad with an image of iOS 9.3.5 which can be downloaded from [IPSW.me](http://ipsw.me).

Carry out the instructions below one by one:

1. **Backup your device**: Connect to iTunes, select your iPad and perform a local backup of the device.
2. **Download iOS software image**: Go to [IPSW.me](https://ipsw.me), choose your device, select the image for the latest iOS release (iOS 9.3.5 in your case) and download it. Note that the latest image will be highlighted in Green with **Signed IPSWs** written on top.

[image]

3. Now in iTunes, select your device, click on Summary, press and hold <kbd>Option</kbd> key and click on **Restore iPad...** button. Browse to the location of the downloaded image and select it.

[image]

4. Once you have restored your device, connect your iPad to iTunes and select **Restore from Backup**.